# Is there anyway to access web version of app store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I would like to see and view those essentials or special landing page that app store has, for example: Essentials for Parents.

I can only view them on app store.

Is there anyway we can access the web view?

These landing page are pretty and I would like to have some idea of the featured banner of each country. It interests me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can actually access the app store through a web URL.**

It is referred to as **iTunes Preview**.
It is mostly text links until you land on the product page.

The web addresses are as follows.

All Itunes Selections and Cetegories: https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/

Just Apps (AppStore): https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8

[image]

[image]